# PaintComponent not working with JButtons - FIXED

Tags: java, layout, jframe, jbutton

EDIT: Thank you everyone, you really helped me out here. The final thing I needed to do was make the panels layout null, so the JButtons could move. Thank you!

My paintComponents content doesn't show up on my programs screen and I think I might've done something wrong with the layouts but I can't figure out why my drawString "Calculator" isn't showing up. Here's my code(I launch the Window from another class called Launcher):

```
    package uusi.projekti.juttu;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Window implements Runnable{

    public Window() {

        JButton button = new JButton("=");
        button.setBounds(530, 510, 50, 50);
        button.setLayout(null);
        button.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");

    //  frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(new drawPanel());
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(new drawPanel());
    }

    public class drawPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Font font = new Font("Arial", 60, 60);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString("Calculator", 100, 100);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
    }
}
```

And here is the Launcher.java

```
package uusi.projekti.juttu;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your main method?

Comment: Edited the original post because the code was unformatted in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

public class Window implements Runnable{

```
public Window() {

    JButton button = new JButton("=");
    button.setBounds(530, 510, 50, 50);
    button.setLayout(null);
    button.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel = new drawPanel();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");

//  frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(panel);

    panel.add(button);
}
```

Comment: Now the calculator string shows up and the button, but I cannot change the location of the button? Do I need to use another type of code to change the location of the button or another layout?